# Multiple sudbomain on Single IP using CONNECT command

Tags: networking, dns, proxy

I have an HTTP proxy application on a server which will route requests for different clients based on the subdomain they used to connect to the proxy.
The proxy, itself being an HTTP one will relay HTTPS request hence the use of *CONNECT* command.

Suppose, a client uses this domain to connect to the proxy: *client-1.example.com*

1) They send a CONNECT line to the proxy to start a connection with a remote target: *host.com*

```
CONNECT host.com:22 HTTP/1.1
Proxy-Authorization: Basic encoded-credentials
```

2) Proxy replies with:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

3) Client starts sending the encrypted part of the HTTPS data which the proxy will simply forward.

My question is that in this whole scheme, how will I read the subdomain used to connect to the proxy: *client-1.example.com*?

I am using a wildcard DNS with **.example.com* which will resolve all subdomains to a single IP.
I need to get the subdomain used so that my proxy can apply some custom routing rules.

Answer (score 1):

> how will I read the subdomain used to connect to the proxy: client-1.example.com?

You won't. As you already see, the proxy name is not included in the requests sent by your clients.

> I need to get the subdomain used so that my proxy can apply some custom routing rules.

You will have to apply the rules based on something else.

- For example, add some indicator to your **usernames** (Proxy-Authorization), so that "someuser@client1" gets one set of rules while "someuser@client2" gets another.
- Alternatively, give *multiple IP addresses* to the proxy server, so that each domain has an unique IP address. Then the proxy can apply rules based on the "local address" that it sees for the connection socket.